# How do i implement a login with google firebase in my java application

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-signin

I've looked at countless youtube videos but nothing try works and I don't know why I've also read through the documentation but with no luck... I'm using android studio and coding in java its a simple problem but I cant seem to figure it out, here is the code I have for the button I've kind of left out the old code that I had in the "//google sign in request" as it does not work and makes no sense. I've also successfully connected my firebase to the project and added the SHA-1 fingerprint.

```
package com.example.firebasegoogleauth4;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.identity.BeginSignInRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.identity.SignInClient;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button btn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        
        btn = findViewById(R.id.button1);
        
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //google sign in request 
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: We really can't tell you what to type here - it's not just a few simple lines, and we don't know what you want the app to actually do here.  You should follow the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/start) exactly as it instructs, and if you have problems with that, show the code you have that doesn't work the way you expect, along with your debugging details.

Comment: What part exactly is not working? Do you have any logs? Does the app crash? You can add log statements to see which part of your code works and which doesn't. You need to add more information here so that, people can figure out what's wrong with your code.

Comment: Try looking at [User Authentication and CRUD Operation with Firebase Realtime Database in Android](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/user-authentication-and-crud-operation-with-firebase-realtime-database-in-android/).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. But since you're using Java, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-create-a-clean-firebase-authentication-using-mvvm-37f9b8eb7336) will help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirebaseAuthentication).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems like you're trying to implement a Google Sign-In functionality using Firebase Authentication in an Android Studio project.

To implement Google Sign-In with Firebase, you'll need to perform the following steps:

1. Add the necessary dependencies: In your project's `build.gradle` file, make sure you have the necessary dependencies for Google Sign-In and Firebase Authentication. For example:

```java
dependencies {
    // Other dependencies...
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:19.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:21.0.1'
}
```

2. Configure Google Sign-In in the Firebase console: Make sure you have enabled the Google Sign-In provider in the Firebase console and added the appropriate SHA-1 fingerprint for your Android app.
3. Set up the Google Sign-In request:

```java
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignIn;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInClient;

// ...

btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        // Configure Google Sign In
        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
                .requestEmail()
                .build();

        // Build a GoogleSignInClient with the options
        GoogleSignInClient googleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(MainActivity.this, gso);

        // Start the sign-in intent
        Intent signInIntent = googleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
    }
});
```

Make sure to replace `R.string.default_web_client_id` with your own web client ID from the Firebase console.

4. Handle the sign-in result:

```java
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
        try {
            // Google sign-in was successful
            GoogleSignInAccount account = task.getResult(ApiException.class);
            
            // Get the user's ID token and authenticate with Firebase
            String idToken = account.getIdToken();
            AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(idToken, null);
            FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signInWithCredential(credential)
                    .addOnCompleteListener(MainActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                // Sign-in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                                FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
                                String displayName = user.getDisplayName();
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Welcome " + displayName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            } else {
                                // Sign-in failed, display a message to the user
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Sign-in failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                    });
        } catch (ApiException e) {
            // Google sign-in failed
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Google Sign-in Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Be sure to define a constant `RC_SIGN_IN` for the request code.

Remember to also set up Firebase Authentication in your project and configure it in the Firebase console.

Make sure you